# unable to update to Ruby 2.1.4

Tags: railstutorial.org

Currently running Yosemite and unable to update to ruby 2.1.4 , see below.

```
Guidos-MacBook-Pro:~ Guido$ rvm install 2.1.4
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.1.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: Sorry for no back story....was trying to update from Ruby 2.0.  I found a few suggestions on here but was not successful.  Any help or explanation of what I am doing wrong is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after I stepped away from the computer for a few hours and came back again, I figured out the issue was that Homebrew was broken after I updated OS to Yosemite.  Here is the link http://ryantvenge.com/2014/09/ruby-homebrea-yosemite/ to the solution.  If that is not working see commands below.

To fix Homebrew:

cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions  
sudo ln -s Current 1.8  
brew update  
sudo rm 1.8

To update to ruby 2.1.4:

rvm install 2.1.4  
rvm use 2.1.4